# Output a list of CD genres (Country, New Age, Jazz, Rock etc.), in order of popularity

Tags: mysql

We have following tables:

Order_Basket:

```
Order_ID (PK)
CD_ID (PK)
```

CD:

```
CD_ID (PK)
Album_ID
Availability
```

Album:

```
Album_ID (PK)
Album_Name
Supplier_ID
Price
Date_Released
Date_Last_Purchased
```

Song:

```
Song_ID (PK)
Song_Name
Genre
Language
Album_ID
```

We assume that one album has 5 songs and this is our sql:

```
SELECT Genre, Count(*)
FROM Order_Basket, CD, Song, Album
WHERE Order_Basket.CD_ID=CD.CD_ID 
AND CD.Album_ID=Album.Album_ID
AND Album.Album_ID=Song.Album_ID
GROUP BY Song.Genre;
```

With the sql above we found total of 220 genres where we have only 44 albums sold. Every genre is repeated 5 times (44x5=220). We also try DISTINCT but the output is still the same (220 in total).

How can we do this correctly?

Comment: Try ```count(DISTINCT Albumn.Albumn_ID)```

Comment: Also, if you are just looking at albumns, why include songs?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: It is because one album has many songs and the songs might have different genre. I try count(DISTINCT Album.Album_ID) it shows syntax error.